# Prove property: Product of perpendiculars from $P$ to sides of isosceles triagle equals square of perpendicular to base $BC$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with vertex at $A$ and $P$ is any point inside the triangle.If the rectangle contained by perpendicular from $P$ to sides $AB$ and $AC$ is equal to square of the perpendicular from $P$ to base $BC$,then prove that the locus of $P$ is a circle.

---

I could not solve this question.I have no idea how to start with.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that $ABC$ is an isosceles _right_ triangle? Otherwise what you claim is a rectangle won't be a rectangle, I think.

Comment: @Arthur, by rectangle, I think he means the product of the two perpendiculars.

Comment: @Apurv When you mention it, that might be too.

Comment: @Apurv,how do you know that rectangle may mean the product of the two perpendiculars.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia, I have come across some problems which use language of this sort. Also, I think that it is the best interpretation of the problem.

Comment: An alternate form of the same question as given in my textbook "Q) A point moves so that the square of its distance from the base of an isosceles triangle is equal to the rectangle contained by its distances from the equal sides of the isosceles triangle , find the locus of such points ?"

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia Title shortened, okay?

Answer (score 0):

> Huge courtesy to a friend Appu.S

Interpreting that rectangle means product of perpendicular distances ...

Consider an Isosceles triangle ABC take base along X axis and with its mid point at origin now take the equation of AB as $y=-mx+c$ and AC as $y=mx-c$.

Take a a point $P(x,y)$ now we have

$$y^{2}=\frac{(y+mx-c)(y-mx+c)}{1+m^{2}}$$

Expand and we have a a circle .

> To understand the interpretation more clearly take a square which has
>   a side of length $y$ (distance of the point from base) therefore area
>   of square = $y^2$ . Similarly draw a possible case where we can get a
>   rectangle formed and since product of adjacent sides of a rectangle =
>   product of perpendicular distances from our point . We have the area
>   of the rectangle hence formed and we are just equating them as per the
>   question.